# JSON parsing in android: No value for x error

Tags: android, json, parsing

Here is the code I'm using inside my AsyncTask

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);    
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
    InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    reader.read(buffer);
    stream.close();

    result = new String(buffer);
    return result;
```

This returns a string result and in my onPostExecute method I try to parse that input string:

```
JSONObject vehicle = new JSONObject(new String(result));
makeEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("make"));
plateEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("plate"));
modelEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("model"));
yearEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("year"));
```

As soon as it reaches makeEdit.setText it throws an error - no value for make. I'm still very new to android, so don't send death threats if there was some obvious error. The input text is the following JSON string:

```
{"GetJSONObjectResult":{"make":"Ford","model":"Focus","plate":"XXO123GP","year":2006}}
```

Comment: First get `GetJSONObjectResult` and then inner values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`No value for x error` message is pretty common when dealing with JSON. This usually resulted by overlooked code.

usually, when dong JSON, I try to see the *human readable* structure first. For that, I usually use [JSONViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

In your case, the structure is something like this:

[image]

You see that `make` is within another object called `GetJSONObjectResult`.  Therefore, to get it, you must first get the container object first:

```
JSONObject vehicle = ((JSONObject)new JSONObject(result)).getJSONObject("GetJSONObjectResult");
//a more easy to read
JSONObject container = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject vehicle = container.getJSONObject("GetJSONObjectResult");
```

and finally use the object to get `make`:

```
makeEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("make"));
plateEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("plate"));
modelEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("model"));
yearEdit.setText(vehicle.getString("year"));
```

Comment: +1 quick one ....but have query, Why JSONObject(new String(result)); why not JSONObject(result); ?

Comment: @DheereshSingh you are right. I was just copy-paste his code and add my fix.

Comment: I didn't know that the vehicle data was wrapped in a container x_x Thank's for the quick reply.

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON Object contains itself a JSONObject. To acces to your data, you have to do like this:

```
vehicle.getJSONObject("GetJSONObjectResult").getString("make");
```

Comment: Thank's Jeje, I tested and this code works too. I would +1 your answer, but my rep is too low :(