# JSON parsing in android: opening objects inside objects

Tags: java, json

This should be really simple and i've been getting close to figuring it out but am starting to loose my sanity. 
Simply trying to pull data from an api

How do i pull JSON data from an object (inside another object)?

This is the first day i've ever heard of JSON so ill be the first to admit i have very little knowledge about this. Thanks for your time!

This post: [JSON parsing in android: No value for x error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947065/json-parsing-in-android-no-value-for-x-error#)    was super helpful and got me to where i am now which is trying to open "list" then get into "0" so i can gather weather data.

Been using jsonviewer.stack to try to understand this stuff

Api url: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=4161254&APPID=e661f5bfc93d47b8ed2689f89678a2c9

My code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView citySpot;
TextView cityTemp;

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            // this works flawlessly and gathers the city name
            JSONObject container = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONObject cityTest = container.getJSONObject("city");

            citySpot.setText(cityTest.getString("name"));

            // this is my failed attempt to get inside of the "list" folder

            JSONObject listList = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONObject listTest = listList.getJSONObject("list");

            JSONObject listTestOne = listTest.getJSONObject("0");

            JSONObject listTestTwo = listTestOne.getJSONObject("main");

            cityTemp.setText(listTestTwo.getString("temp"));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    citySpot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
    cityTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();

        task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=4161254&APPID=e661f5bfc93d47b8ed2689f89678a2c9");


}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: `[` starts an array. `{` starts an object. There is no object with key `"0"` and `list` is mapped to an array

Comment: Also `container` and `listTest` are equal, so you only need the former

Comment: Figured it out by doing this:   Thanks for the tip!                                                                       JSONArray listArray = container.getJSONArray("list");

                JSONObject listZero = listArray.getJSONObject(0);

                JSONObject listMain = listZero.getJSONObject("main");

                cityTemp.setText(listMain.getString("temp"));

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to answer your own question below as an actual answer, which you can accept to know that you've solved your post.

Answer (score 1):

You could try use gson library to parse the response. Add below in build.gradle

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'
```

Create beans to match your response. Use fields to match what comes back in the json response. Sample below.

```
public class ResultsResponse {
    private List<MyList> list;
}
public class MyList {
    private String main;
}
```

If you want `MyList` can have another list. Finally try

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder =  new GsonBuilder();
ResultsResponse response = gsonBuilder.create().fromJson(jsonString, ResultsResponse.class)
```

`response` object should have your list populated.

Comment: How does this address the problem in the question?